# Adding extra layout to specific controllers and actions in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my application.html.erb I have a **header partial.** which I rendered with the render tag

```
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
```

So this header applies to all the controller and all the actions.

I have a **dropdown partial** which i want to show, **in addition to the header partial**, in all the controllers **except one one controller.** I want something like

```
<%= render 'layouts/dropdown' except_controller_anycontroller %>
```

When I put

```
render :partial => 'layouts/dropdown'
```

It just renders the dropdown partial and all other layouts are lost (like the footer,header,body). I want to add the extra dropdown partial only to certain actions and controllers.

How can I achieve that in Rails 3.2.13?

Comment: Make sure your are calling all these partials from your layout file. Otherwise i can't see any reason why your `header, footer` etc missing.

Comment: @Manoj well I know I can call them from layout files but that will be repetition of code. I just don't want that in a single controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your render with this:

```
 <%= render 'layouts/dropdown' unless @disable_dropdown %>
```

Then you can simply set disable_dropdown to true in any controller you like:

```
def test_method
  @disable_dropdown = true
end
```

call this method in your controller filter, in which you dont want to show this:

write this on top of your controller above your first method:

```
before_filter :test_method
```

it will automatically be called when your request comes to this controller.

Hope it will help. Thanks

Comment: How to set disable_dropdown to true in controller?

Comment: I have updated my answer. use before_filter for that in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like:

```
<%= render 'layouts/dropdown' unless params[:controller] == "controller_to_avoid" %>
```

Comment: That's giving me the same problem I mentioned in my edit.It's only rendering the dropdown partial and not the other one's.

Comment: @Mrudul_T There's another issue there then. That code wouldn't affect other partials being rendered.

Comment: Sorry.Didn't get you.You mean there's another bug in my code?

Comment: The answer I gave would not stop another partial from being rendered. Did you place it in your `application.html.erb`? along with `<%= render 'layouts/header'%>`.

Comment: Yup I put it just beside that.